# What type of trailer plug is this?

Tags: wiring, trailer

I can't for the life of me figure out what type of trailer light adapter this is. It's on a 2006 Toyota tacoma. It doesn't fit any standard 7 way plugs. I have an adapter that looks similar but the pins are angled just slightly differently.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It's a 7-way trailer & RV plug. Here's the layout:

(From the vehicle side)

[image]

(From the trailer side)

[image]

Note: Images used from [this website.](https://www.ajtnt.com/Info/7-Way-Diagram) ... no affiliation.

Comment: That diagram does match the plug and I have a standard 7 way plug, it doesn't fit.

Comment: The only suggestion I have for you, then, is to get one which does fit? I would think if anything is not fitting on it, it's the center pin (backup lights - #7). Some are round while others are flat.

Comment: Problem is I can't find anything that fits. Nothing at the store does and I can't tell what type it is.

Comment: What I'd suggest is to get the one *which fits the trailer* and replace the one on the vehicle ... there's more than one way to skin a cat. You can verify the pin out as shown above matches the trailer.

Comment: Ah okay. I actually have that already, but the one on the truck does not match your diagram. It has a black wire and two yellow wires. I guess I'll just have to manually test them and figure out what's what.

Comment: @TheShoeShiner, there are a couple types of 7 pin round adapters, each with their unique pin mappings. Search for "7 blade to 7 pin" adapters. (Might be what you're looking for.) It would also be nice to see a picture of the trail plug you're trying to attach, so we could further assist in creating the connection.

Comment: @the_storyteller I ended up manually wiring a standard 7 blade connector based on trial and error. I still have no clue what the name of that connector is, and have yet to find an adapter that fits it.